# HTML <input type="text"... as <input type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

How to set `<input type="text"...` to be read-only but to allow deletion of its value?

In other words how to achieve behavior like `<input type="file"...`, where you cannot manually enter path to file but you can delete what has been injected by "Browse" button.

Comment: Probably impossible without JavaScript. Can you use it? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: yes I am very open to any javascript

Comment: check my answer, you can also move the onclick to the type=text field if you want to clear it onclick

Comment: What I am looking is input type="text" that does not allow entering vales, but it allows deleting with delete button and backspace button from keyboard

Answer (score 1):

jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name" readonly="readonly" value="demovalue" />
<input type="button" onclick="$('#name1').val('');" value="clear">
```

basic:

```
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name" readonly="readonly" value="demovalue" />
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('name1').value='';" value="clear">
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering this HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="onlydelete" value="Nyedva Nyedva" />
```

The following jQuery function will only allow the Backspace key to be used in the input fields with class `onlydelete`.

```
$('.onlydelete').keypress(function (e) {
    return (e.which===8);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found that you also need the Delete key. And I guess you would also like to allow the arrow keys to let the user move the caret. For these special keys, you can use keydown. The following snippet only allows Delete (46), Backspace (8), and arrow keys (37-40).

```
$('.onlydelete').keydown(function (e) {
    return (e.which===46 || e.which===8 || (e.which>=37 && e.which<=40));
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The other good thing about adding a class is that you can easily style these special inputs with css. For example:

```
.onlydelete { background-color: #aaaaaa; }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.value='',this.disabled='disabled'" value="text">
```

if you don't want to change the background to grey, you can add and the following css:

```
input[disabled] {background:white;border:1px solid #7F9DB9}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/utw8y/1

*Update*

Using only delete or backspace keys you can use the following jQuery code:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
    if ((event.which!='0') && (event.which!='8')) {
     event.preventDefault();
    } else {
    $(this).val("");    
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/utw8y/2/

Comment: Not exactly, can I delete vale only with delete button and backspace button from keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");

inputBox.onkeypress = checkInput;

function checkInput(e) {
  // checking if the pressed key is delete or backspace
  // if not, we prevent character input
  if (e.keyCode != 8 || e.keyCode != 46) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

// also a button to clear the input value
document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {
  inputBox.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="this is a test" />
<input type="button" id="delete" value="delete" />
```